# Why docker bash doesn't see the cross compiler

Tags: docker, cross-compiling, toolchain

I have created a docker container to compile a single C code by using a toolchain.

First created a docker container by using the command below;

```
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  -v "$(pwd)"/target:/app \
  ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

Then copied my toolchain file in the docker container by using a linked directory and tried to compile my single C code in docker container by using the following command;

```
./arm-none-eabi-gcc test.c
```

But it returns me;

```
bash: ./arm-none-eabi-gcc: No such file or directory
```

I can run the command above in my local ubuntu machine and it worked well but in the docker container it returns me the `No such file or directory` error. Why?

Comment: are you in the `/app` directory?

Comment: no. I am in the /root directory

Comment: How do you expect `./arm-none-eabi-gcc` to exist in `/root` when you mount it in `/app`?

Comment: I copied it to the root file from the app file

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand the problem you describe.
To reproduce I did the following:

### Setup the Docker Container

Your command:

```sh
docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  -v "$(pwd)"/target:/app \
  ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

### Enter the Container and install gcc

```sh
docker exev -it devtest /bin/bash

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install build-essential
```

### Test if gcc what available in the Container

```sh
root@a0989b9966c2:/app# gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
```

### On the Host create a dummy c file in the target directory

```sh
cd target
touch test.c
```

#### C file has the following contents

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf ("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

### Compile it in the Container

```sh
root@a0989b9966c2:/# cd /app
root@a0989b9966c2:/app# gcc test.c
root@a0989b9966c2:/app# ls 
a.out*  test.c
```

### In the Container, run the file

```sh
root@a0989b9966c2:/app# cd /app
root@a0989b9966c2:/app# ./a.out
Hello, world!
root@a0989b9966c2:/app#
```

Looks ok.